# Positioning button "outside" its container

Tags: html, css, button, position

I am trying to position a button outside its container (a div), so that it will remain visible if the content in the container scrolls.

The user sees an object that references a separate HTML page which contains a bit of script that fetches a random string (a quote from Somebody Famous) from a text file.

Code for user view:

```
<div style="position:relative;padding-top:1.3em;padding-left:100px;">
<b>Quote-of-the-Moment</b>
<object type="text/html" data="./quotes.html" style="width:73%;overflow:auto;background-color:lightyellow;position:relative;padding-top:7px;height:150px;"></object>
</div>
```

Code for the referenced "quotes.html"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rantex.php"></script>
<div style="padding-top:10px;">
<input type='button' onclick='location.reload();' value='Get another quote' style="background:navy;color:white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;border-radius: 8px;" />
</div>
```

I have tried "position:relative;top:50px" in the div definition and in the button definition, but all that  does is position the button lower in the container, and it disappears when the fetched content "overflows".

What I want is for the button to appear below the container so that it remains visible when the referenced quote causes the object referencing "quotes.html" to display a scrollbar.
[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b09I2.png) [how I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhbhl.png)

Comment: So as far as I understood you want the button to appear outside of the container. For that you should also have the button outside of the container. So you place the button in a new div which is underneath the first div.

Comment: And could you also provide us a Snippet where we can execute it so we get the same result as you do.

Comment: Looks like your button element is inside of the same container as the quote, i.e. both the quote and the button are inside a parent element which sets the background and overflow behaviour etc. If you can't move the button to the same level as the parent, you could try setting something like `position: absolute; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: -50px` on the button.

Comment: If I put the button outside the container, e.g., in its own div, it refreshes the whole page, not just the quote.

Comment: The working page is at
http://www.illuminedliving.com/

Comment: So here's the hierarchy:
The visible page loads quotes.html in a div.

quotes.html runs the script and loads the button on page load. The button re-runs the script and fetches a new quote.

However, the code
````
<div>
<input type='button' onclick='location.reload();' value='Get another quote' style="background:navy;color:white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;border-radius: 8px;position: absolute; bottom: 0;left:73px; margin-bottom: -20px;" />
</div>
````

just places the button out of sight behind the edge of the div, not below it.

Comment: I'd attach a screenshot, but I don't see the controls for it in this comment.